# Pre fill the password field

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-forms

I want to pre-fill the password field from the Cookie. I am setting `#value`, but it is not rendered. I have also tried `#default_value`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password textfield doesn't use `#default_value`, as reported in [Form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6).
You should implement your own form field, to pre-fill the password textfield. I am not sure if browsers would permit a password textfield to be pre-filled, though.

Comment: Most of them do. I actually haven't seen one that doesn't.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Earlier i had tried with the html input(without using the form api) which worked . Now i am using the drupal's user_login form and in the pre-process method trying to set the password. For user name field its working. What could be the alternative ?

Comment: Apart what I suggested, I cannot see other alternatives; there is no way to alter the output returned from each implementation of hook_elements() (Drupal core code does not use hook_elements_alter(), or you would be able to change the implementation of the password form field done by system.module.